# ifconfig doesn't work on Android 10 (permission denied)

Tags: android, android-10.0, ifconfig

When I try to run ifconfig on Oculus Quest 2 (Android 10) I get a 'permission Denied' error:

```
ifconfig: ioctl 8927: Permission denied
```

Any alternatives/solution to this?

Comment: is it a programming question? alternative to get what? get it running? change phone, root phone ... from the programming perspective there is no `ifconfig` - it's not a part of Android's API

Comment: rooting is not an option since I'm not allowd to change the device settings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eventually I found an alternative command that works on Android 10 (even the output is different from ifconfig's):

```
ip -f inet addr show
```